# ADAL authentication for multiple plugins webapp

Tags: active-directory, azure-active-directory, adal

I have a web application with multiple plugins on a single page. User can select which plugin to run at any given time. There can be multiple plugins running at the same time.

I am writing a plugin which will authenticate user and get claims from Authorization server and use it to get tokens for apps it is using. Now the question is - can any other plugin running in the same session see my tokens? It seems yes since its stored in browser's session/local store. Is there a way to avoid this?

Another question:  I want all the plugins to have separate clientIds and each plugin should have access to its own relevant backend. If all of them share the same context (which it seems they do), I will have to give this client access to all (~100) backends which is not acceptable. So, can other plugins create a different authentication context?

Comment: In my opinion , you could encrypt the values , but you need to modify the ADAL to add the encrypt/decrypt function .

Answer (score 0):

The Azure AD session is associated with the domain.
If the plugins are using the same domain then they will be able to access the shared session for that domain. This means that they can access the cookies,state stored in the session. However, the tokens issued identifies a specific plugin and provides it the resource access, so the token cannot be used by other plugins.

Comment: Thanks Navya! However, this doesn't answer my next question - can each plugin create its own authentication context (with its clientId)?

Comment: Can you explain a little further what a plugin is with respect to your application structure? Is each plugin a web app?

Comment: No, there are multiple plugins in the webpage. To understand it from very high level, there are multiple plugins on the web page. Each plugin is responsible for fetching data from service over Azure and rendering a part of the web page. You should be able to visit the page - http://qptest/. So, there are ~50 plugins (which can be run theoretically at the same time to load the page) and each should have access to some azure services.  Now I don't want to share the authentication context across all the plugins since I want each plugin to have its own clientId.

Comment: Basically, each plugin can be called a web app. And there are multiple plugins on single page. Hope that helps understand my scenario.

Comment: Looking at the ADAL code https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/adal.js it seems AuthenticationContext is sitting in global scope and there can be only one instance of it per window(singleton pattern). So all plugins will have to share the context. Not sure why thats the case.